# Get a button to delete a record and link to another page

Tags: php, html

I am displaying an HTML table of appointment bookings, and in each row there is a button that lets the user delete each individual booking. Currently it instantly deletes the record, but I was wondering if it was possible to display some sort of confirmation message before deleting, and if it was also possible to redirect the user to a new page at the same time.

```
<?php

    require('header.php');
    require('config/db_connect.php');
    adminCheck();

    $adminEmail = $_SESSION['email'];

        // make sql 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email='$adminEmail'";

        // get query result
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        // fetch result in assoc array (one row, single student)
        $bookings = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    

        if (isset($_GET['deleteId'])) {
            // Sanitize input for SQL injection risk
            $deleteId = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['deleteId']);
          
            if(!is_null($deleteId)) {
              $sqlB = "DELETE FROM bookings WHERE id = '$deleteId'";
              mysqli_query($connection, $sqlB);
              // Could use a modal otherwise this instantly deletes the record
            }
          }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <h2> All bookings </h2> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <table class='striped white'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Surname</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        // This doesn't echo the first record in the database for some reason
                        echo 
                        "<tr>".
                        "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['firstName'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['surName'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['date'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['timeSlot'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td><a href=\"mmAdmin.php?deleteId={$row['id']}\">Delete Row</a></td>" . // trying to link to a new page too
                        "</tr>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo 'no bookings';
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body> 
</html>

<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Furthermore, when the table is displayed, the first record is always missing for some reason too. Is there something I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: `I was wondering if it was possible to display some sort of confirmation message before deleting`...yes using JavaScript

Comment: `it was also possible to redirect the user to a new page at the same time`...yes. Google how to do a redirect using PHP

Comment: And you don't see the first row because `$bookings = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` already gets the first row and puts it into `$bookings`, but then you don't seem to do anything with it - it's unclear what that line is supposed to be for?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Even escaping the values does not provide full protection. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could potentially steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, you can do something like this, using javascript to ask for confirmation

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')){ location.href='mmAdmin.php?deleteId={$row['id']}\">Delete Row</a></td>'; }">Delete row </a>
```

For the second thing, maybe try to add an html redirect only if there is the get variable set

```
    <?php if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])) { ?>
           <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: why would you bother with a 0-second meta redirect instead of setting a Location header?